Import products to customers cart
Is that possible to add products into customer woocommerce cart by CSV file with customers ID and list of products ID?
As I know customer cart stores in local storage. Lifetime of cart on site set to 1 month and now needed to be moved to other site without any actions from customers.
To add items I'd think to use
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart()

But there also questions how to take it with list of customers
